# simple taming calculator project

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class tame_dilo:

    torpor = 250

    def __init__(self, name, effect):
        self.name = name
        self.effect = effect

    def attack(self):
        self.torpor = self.torpor - self.effect

dilo = tame_dilo('dilo', 25)

dilo.attack()
print(dilo.torpor)

class tame_sable(tame_dilo):
    torpor = 500

sable = tame_sable('sable', 25)

sable.attack()
print(sable.torpor)
```

I just started learning some oop on python and I decide to do this little project to practice a little.
What I want to know is, if Im using the proper way to relate the name of the creature with its torpor by using  inheritance and some polymorphism to define a diferent torpor according to the creatur class.

And also i want to know what would be the proper method so the user can change the effect of the attack method like if you were using better equitment to knock the creature.

Comment: All `tame_dilo` have the same `torpor`. If you make multiple instances, they all share that one value. In other words, attacking one, affects them all. You should define it within `__init__` unless you want that

Comment: I try defining both tropor and effect with the __init__ method but i got an error so I decided to create different classes so i could vary the torpor and then used inheritance to save some code

Comment: And what was the error?

Comment: You can still use inheritance, but I see no reason to. All you've done is give a different value, not overwritten any class behavior. In other words, just use a different parameter value for the tropor

Comment: What would be the proper way to do input in python oop, i was looking around but i got a little confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dilo and a sable are a type of tame. They are instances, not classes.

Therefore, you need one class capable of holding different attributes.

Also, assuming torpor is health, or energy,  I'm not sure why the attack function is affecting itself. Shouldn't an instance be attacking something else?

```
class Tame:

    def __init__(self, name, effect, torpor):
        self.name = name
        self.effect = effect
        self.torpor = torpor

    def attack(self, other):
        other.torpor -= self.effect
```

Now you create named instances

```
dilo = Tame('dilo', 25, 250)
sable = Tame('sable', 25, 500)
dilo.attack(sable)
print(sable.torpor)
```

To change the effect of a tame, just update it

```
dilo.effect += 10
```

Comment: what if i want the user to change the effect value by percent? what i mean is that i want to be able to enter an specific value

Comment: Then multiply by `1+percent`